# How to get Access Key and Secrete Access Key If I know aws username and password by programmingly

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am developing some windows application which need to communicate with Amazon AWS S3 to get the data and store the data. Now the end client doesn't know about the Access key and secret access key which knows about the username and password so I have to get username and password and then communicate the aws s3 but to communicate with s3 we need the access key and secret access key so How can I able to get Access Key and Secret Access Key from the username and password using programming?

Comment: you can move your writing and reading from S3 to a web api which can run in aws itself. there you can have the credentials in aws KMS or store in a config file in the api app itself in an encrypted fashion. the client app will simply call the api and does not need to know the credentials.

Comment: thanks @Aravind, but we don't want to implement a web API. but is it possible that on the server side we create IAM users which have a very limited time to use and get this IAM user's Access and Secret Access keys? How can we able to do this?

Comment: Do you just want these users to be able to upload/download data to S3? I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command. Yes, it needs the Access Key & Secret Key. You should **not** be providing them with login credentials to the AWS Management Console. That is only for use by _your_ staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using username and password is considered a bad security practice. The end user should obtain IAM access key and provide it to the software. Please, review "Best Practices for Managing AWS Access Keys" guide from AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html.

Second, there is no way to retrieve existing key after it has been created. You can create IAM access keys programmatically from your application using AWS SDK (example for Node.js: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/iam-examples-managing-access-keys.html), but to set up SDK you will need a key in the first place.

I would re-engineer the application and require API keys instead of username/password.

Comment: Not sure why you are saying username/password is a bad security practice. It is the best practice if the access is through AWS console which most users are familiar with. Of course you need to manage the IAM users with the correct IAM policy and MFA. Not everyone uses SDK or CLI to access AWS resources. Keys can be created anytime and can be made inactive anytime.